# Google Sheet if condition continue even if value not in range

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements

```
function checkRowCol(row, col) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (13 <= row <= 16 || 29 <= row <= 32 || 45 <= row <= 48 || 61 <= row <= 64 || 77 <= row <= 80 || 93 <= row <= 96 || 109 <= row <= 112 || 125 <= row <= 128) {
    
    if (col == 6 || col == 12 || col == 18){
      if (13 <= row <= 16 || 29 <= row <= 32 || 45 <= row <= 48 || 61 <= row <= 64 || 77 <= row <= 80 || 93 <= row <= 96 || 109 <= row <= 112 || 125 <= row <= 128) {
      ownedUpdate(row, col);
      }
    }
    // complete
    else if(col == 3 || col == 9 || col == 15) {
      if (13 <= row <= 16 || 29 <= row <= 32 || 45 <= row <= 48 || 61 <= row <= 64 || 77 <= row <= 80 || 93 <= row <= 96 || 109 <= row <= 112 || 125 <= row <= 128) {
        if (ws.getRange(row, col + 3).getValue() == false && ws.getRange(row, col ).getValue() == true) {
          ws.getRange(row, col).setValue(false);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("You cannot complete without owning the item sir");
        }
        else {
            completedUpdate(row, col);
            if (ws.getRange(row, col).getValue() == true){
              ownedUpdate(row, col + 3);
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have this code block, I've made that if col 6 row 17 is changed so nothing will happen but for some reason it still enters the if that prints ("You cannot complete without owning the item sir") and I can't seem to understand why.
I've try putting the ranges in "(13 <= row <= 16)...."
I've tried as you seen to make extra ifs with the condition.
but for some reason it still enters when Row 17 is selected... can't understand why

Tried to enter value row = 17, col= 3 result was

```
if (ws.getRange(row, col + 3).getValue() == false && ws.getRange(row, col ).getValue() == true) {
          ws.getRange(row, col).setValue(false);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("You cannot complete without owning the item sir");
        }
```

tried multiple ifs, tried even the negative ifs that should not end in this result and still... that's what I get...
:help: